# How to get reanimated working in Snack Expo

Tags: react-native, animation, expo

I'm trying to get reanimated (https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-reanimated) running on Expo Snack, but I keep getting this error on my phone.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor 
(evaluating 'new _reactNativeReanimated.default.Value(0)')
```

And on Expo Snack

```
Error: "Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined" in TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'Value' of undefined << at new App (module://App.js.js!transpiled:47:53) 
<< at so ([snack internals] << at Mi ([snack internals] ...
```

I created a simple Expo Snack demonstrating this problem, which is available here https://snack.expo.io/@benjeau/reanimated-problem. How can this be fixed?

Here is the code of the Snack.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  test = new Animated.Value(0);

  render() {
    return (
      <View />
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use reanimated in an Expo Snack, you need to import the **NativeModules** from react-native and get the **UIManager** from it. Ex:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { UIManager } = NativeModules;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  test = new Animated.Value(0);

  render() {
    return (
      <View />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Change the version of expo and test with different versions.**
here at bottom bar is an option to change expo version in snack.expo
[image]